# Filter() function not recognizing my data

Tags: r, filter

I have come across some trouble while trying to filter my dataset.

My dataset contains information regarding the Dow  Jones Index data, there are 750 observations and 16 variables. (I will attach a screenshot as pasting the code makes it look messy and complex):[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWQgj.png)

For more information, I have divided the Dow Jones Index data into subsets named Quarter_1 and Quarter_2.
My goal was to use the Quarter_1 data and split the stocks into groups by their industries for my assignment.
It has worked before but all of a sudden, the code does not recognize the variable "Stock".

```
TechIndustry_Q1 <- filter(Quarter_1, stock == "CSCO" | stock == "IBM" | stock == "INTC" | stock == "MSFT")
PharmIndustry_Q1 <- filter(Quarter_1, stock == "JNJ" | stock == "MRK")
FinanceIndustry_Q1 <- filter(Quarter_1, stock == "AXP" | stock == "JPM" | stock == "TRV")
RetailIndustry_Q1 <- filter(Quarter_1,  stock == "HD" | stock == "WMT" | stock == "PG" | stock == "KO")
```

which produces this error:

```
Error in filter(Quarter_1, stock == "CSCO" | stock == "IBM" | stock ==  : object 'stock' not found
```

I would appreciate your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is based on using wrong `filter` function.  There is a `stats::filter` whose behaviour is different than the `dplyr::filter`.  Suppose, we don't load any packages,

```
filter(mtcars, mpg > 15)
#Error in filter(mtcars, mpg > 15) : object 'mpg' not found
```

as it is the `stats::filter`

After loading the package

```
library(dplyr)
filter(mtcars, mpg > 15)
#                    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710        22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#Valiant           18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#Merc 240D         24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#Merc 230          22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#Merc 280          19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
# ...
```

---

Or even without loading the package, can make use of the function with `::`

```
dplyr::filter(mtcars, mpg > 15)
```

---

The OP's code can be shortened to

```
dplyr::filter(Quarter_1, stock %in% c("CSCO", "IBM", "INTC", "MSFT"))
```

Or create a grouping column

```
Quarter1 <- Quarter1 %>%
     mutate(grp = case_when(stock %in% 
          c("CSCO", "IBM", "INTC", "MSFT") ~ "TechIndustry",
      stock %in% c("JNJ", "MRK") ~ "PharmIndustry",
      stock %in% c("AXP", "JPM", "TRV") ~ "FinanceIndustry",
      stock %in% c("HD", "WMT", "PG", "KO") ~ "RetailIndustry"))
```